# Finding the position vector of extensions

Tags: vectors

I have this triangle[image]

And this problem

> OM is extended to C.
>   The position vector of C is a+kb. Find k

How can i find k here? I know the position vector of M is '2/5a+3/5b'.

Comment: What is the meaning of $C$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that
\begin{align}
\vec{OM}=t\mathbf{a}+(1-t)\mathbf{b}
\end{align}
for some $0\leq t \leq 1$. Here, it is clear that $t=\frac{2}{5}$.
Hence we have
\begin{align}
\vec{OM}=\frac{2}{5}\mathbf{a}+\frac{3}{5}\mathbf{b} \ \implies \ \ \frac{5}{2}\vec{OM} = \mathbf{a}+\frac{3}{2}\mathbf{b}.
\end{align}